# Refresh part of a webpage using Python

Tags: python, css, refresh, element, reload

Just querying whether it is possible to partially refresh a webpage. My aim is to keep refreshing an element until it is clickable and just partially refreshing the webpage would be a big advantage.

Comment: Is this for the application (ie user facing) or is this a requirement for some kind of UI testing?

Comment: Not entirely sure I know what you mean. I’m using it on chrome driver for a website. Need to refresh their webpage but I only need to refresh an element on the webpage.